# Set TCP client socket to non-blocking: Server vs client

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I have a question regarding non-blocking sockets in TCP connections.

I have implemented two c++ classes, one for the tcp server and one for the client. The server has two sockets file descriptors, one for the server and one for the client. The client has one socket file descriptor.

My server runs asynchronously and my client runs at a fixed rate. Therefore I would like to have a non-blocking socket for sending data from the client to the server, s.t. the client can send data at a fixed rate without stalling and the server asynchronously reads all data that has been buffered meanwhile.

So my question is: **Does it make a difference, if I set the client socket to non-blocking in the client or the server class?** (using `fcntl(this->newsockfd_, F_SETFL, fcntl(this->newsockfd_, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK)`, where `this->newsockfd_` is the client's socket file descriptor in both classes)

I tried this in my programm and it seemed like setting the client socket to non-blocking in the client-class didn't do the trick, but setting it in the server-class did. However, I don't understand why this should make a difference.

Comment: A difference in what? Set the socket to non-blocking means the socket reads, writes, and other socket operations will return immediately. You must then be prepared to handle the cases where no data was transferred because the operation would normally have blocked because there was no data available to read, or the outbound network buffers were full, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If your socket is set to non blocking mode, you will get just that. It will never block. But that does not mean that your api calls will succeed.

There are buffers that are being used behind the scenes and if they are full, which would mean in blocking mode that the socket would block, you will get a return code EWOULDBLOCK, which means that your sent has failed. This means that you basically have to wait for the buffers to empty and then try again.

Your idea of sending at an even rate despite of the server rate to receive, is impossible. You cannot have a client sending at a fixed rate. The whole idea of TCP is that there is a constant negotiation between client and server and the speed will be heavily depending on the network conditions. Congestion and the like.

Moving to non blocking sockets creates some problems of its own. You have to detect that the send fails, you have to check if the socket becomes writeable again, you have to store the bytes that you tried to send, and reattempt a send as soon as the socket becomes writable again.

There is a lot of difference on both client and server between working with blocking and non blocking sockets. non blocking sockets are in my opinion more difficult to be dealt with. You need the select api, with a timeout very likely to detect all the possible socket states. In case of blocking sockets, you can just use a socket in a thread, and if the socket blocks, it is just the thread that will block as well. If your gui is on a different thread, the GUI will be responsive.

Answer (score -1):

Since your client is only sending data the non-blocking setting will not effect it. According to the excellent [beej.us guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#blocking) on socket programming, only calls to `accept()` and `recv()` are effected by the non-blocking setting. Since only your server is calling these you are seeing the change on your server code. If your client received data then the non-blocking setting would effect it and you would have to use `select()` to check if there is data and read from it accordingly.

Comment: This answer is wrong because a send can block as well. beej says Lots of functions block. accept() blocks. All the recv() functions block.  accept and recv are not lots of functions, just 2 examples of functions that can block. As said, send can block as well.

Comment: Your citation don't say what you claim, and a third party website isn't a normative reference. You should be citing the *man* pages or Posix, which don't say that either.